# Populate dropdown from database

Tags: database, dropdown, select

I am creating a custom plugin for our martial arts school and have come up against a problem that is doing my head in. No doubt I am missing something obvious but have never really dealt with Wordpress in this capacity before so rather than smash my computer, thought I would ask the brains trust what I am doing wrong ;)

the following code works perfectly and generates the dropdown:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "testing_db";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

?>
<html>
<body>

<select name="dojang">
        <option selected="selected">Choose…</option>
<?php 
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT dojangName FROM wp_tmadm_dojangs");

while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
    $dojang = $row['dojangName'];
    echo "<option value='$dojang'>$dojang</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

but the following doesn't work from within Wordpress:

```
<select name="dojang">
    <option selected="selected">Choose…</option>

<?php 
global $wpdb;

$sql = $wpdb->mysqli_query("SELECT dojangName FROM wp_tmadm_dojangs");

while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
    $dojang = $row['dojangName'];
    echo "<option value='$dojang'>$dojang</option>";
}
?>

</select>
```

Am I not connecting to the database correctly?
Is there something else I am missing?

Appreciate any help.
Thanks

EDIT: Apologies, I pasted the wrong code in the 2nd block - should have been `mysql_query`, not `get_results`

Comment: `$wpdb->get_results()` returns an array, so you should just do `foreach ( $sql as $row ) { echo $row->dojangName; ... }`. Have a look at the [reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/).

Comment: @SallyCJ Apologies, I pasted the wrong code in the 2nd block - should have been `mysql_query`, not `get_results`. Does that make any difference to your answer?

Comment: `$wpdb` doesn't have a `mysqli_query()` method. That might be just a typo, but couldn't resist in saying it.. But then, if the table is in the WordPress database, why not just use `$wpdb->get_results()`? Have you tried the `foreach` in my previous comment? Did it work?

Comment: @SallyCJ Thanks, I think this is where I am getting confused. Obviously a lot has changed since the last time I used php for anything meaningful :D.  I am unclear how I get the $row into the <option> tags though

Comment: Well, I hope the answer helps you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that `testing_db` is your WordPress database, then you should use the WordPress [`wpdb` API/class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/) to interact with the data in your custom table (`wp_tmadm_dojangs`).

So if this is how you do it in "regular PHP", i.e. using native PHP functions:

```php
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT dojangName FROM wp_tmadm_dojangs");

while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
    $dojang = $row['dojangName'];
    echo "<option value='$dojang'>$dojang</option>";
}
```

Then in WordPress, this is one way of how you can do it:

```php
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT dojangName FROM {$wpdb->prefix}tmadm_dojangs", ARRAY_A );
var_dump( $results ); // for debugging

foreach ( $results as $row ) {
    $dojang = $row['dojangName'];
    echo "<option value='$dojang'>$dojang</option>";
}
```

Please check the `$wpdb->get_results()` (or `wpdb::get_results()`) [reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/) for details on the function's syntax, parameters, etc, but what I can tell you from the above example are:

1. `$wpdb->get_results()` returns an array of rows from the queried table and by default, each row is a PHP *object* with each column as a property in the object, e.g. `$row->dojangName`.

   However, in the code, you could see I used the `ARRAY_A` constant which gives us each row as an associative array with the table column as the array key, e.g. `$row['dojangName']`.

   But regardless it's an object or associative array, the value is of course the (raw) value in the corresponding database column.
2. If you're retrieving a single column/field from the database table, then you can just use [`$wpdb->get_col()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_col/) which returns the column values in an indexed array, i.e. `array( 0 => 'value', 1 => 'value2', 2 => 'value3', ... )`.
3. I presumed your WordPress database (table) prefix is `wp_`, and instead of hard-coding the prefix, you should use `$wpdb->prefix` to get the prefix.

So using `$wpdb->get_col()`, the example I gave would be:

```php
$results = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT dojangName FROM {$wpdb->prefix}tmadm_dojangs" );
var_dump( $results ); // for debugging

foreach ( $results as $dojang ) {
    echo "<option value='$dojang'>$dojang</option>";
}
```

Btw, please make sure you escape the database values prior to presenting them to the user. E.g. `echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $dojang ) . '">' . esc_html( $dojang ) . '</option>';`

Comment: Thank you very much. It would seem I have a lot to un-learn :D